# Corruption when exporting PDF from Photoshop CS6

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf

My document looks like this:

[image]

I save as a PDF from Photoshop, using the default High Print Quality setting. The resulting PDF looks like this:

[image]

What's going on?

Comment: Is that how the pdf file looks if you for example open it up inside photoshop, or when viewing it by some other means? ( That looks a lot like the stuff that often happens when viewing files with the Quick look file preview `spacebar` in osx )

Comment: Just opening with Preview on Mac. In the end I just flattened the image before saving as a PDF...

Comment: Try opening with Adobe Acrobat or Acrobat Reader. Preview has some issues with certain elements in PDFs.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop is terrible at exporting PDF files. Silly that Adobe can't get it right. PDF files exported out of Photoshop are ridiculously huge in file size, which might have something to do with it, particularly because you're rendering it at high quality print. Is the file really large? How many MB?

A workaround I use is by saving it out as a PNG then putting the PNG image into inDesign and saving it as a PDF from there. The resulting file size is about 50x smaller than the bloated PDF Photoshop puts out.